# Describe table SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How to describe table in SQL Oracle, I tried desc and describe, but it says desc not supported. I also tried mysql syntax show columns from table, but show is also unsupported?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't say what UI you are using, but `DESC` works in all of them that I know of. If it doesn't

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE'
AND OWNER = 'MY_SCHEMA';
```

is an alternative for getting the same information.

Comment: This worked perfect to me! 4 years latter.... ;)

Comment: This happened to me when I was using Oracle Live SQL online. ( https://livesql.oracle.com ). Your solution worked for me too.